# Django - How to remove F() from a field?

Tags: django, expression

after doing a query with `F()` (see http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions), I save the object, but then, I need to save it again. I want to remove F() from the field. If I don't, F() gets called again.

For example

```
rank.ammountMatchesRanked = F('ammountMatchesRanked') + 1
rank.save() # does ammountMatchesRanked = ammountMatchesRanked + 1
... # Manipulating more rank fields (can't manipulate before)
rank.save() # does ammountMatchesRanked++ again (undesired)
```

Any idea on how can I clear reference fields? I have searched the documentation but I didn't find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not that good in django, but what about doing this:

```
rank.ammountMatchesRanked = F('ammountMatchesRanked');
```

just before the second call?

Comment: Hey dusoft, this worked, thanks! Before marking you as accepted solution I will wait to see if anyone has a better way. Doing what you suggested is probably inserting something like SET ammountMatchesRanked=ammountMatchesRanked on the update query, which is unnecessary

Comment: is there option to `unset(rank.ammountMatchesRanked)` ?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `F()` here at all? `F` is really for use within queries, where you want to just get those objects who have a certain property with some relation to another property in the same model. Once you've got the object, there's no need to use it - you can just do it in standard Python:

```
rank.ammountMatchesRanked += 1
rank.save()
```

**Edited after comment** No, you have misunderstood what lazy loading is. It applies to instances (ie database rows) within a queryset, not fields (ie columns) within an instance. So once you have accessed an instance at all, Django by default will load all its fields (except those you have marked with `defer()`), so the above will not result in an extra query.

The documentation for using `F()` in updates which you linked to explains that this is only if you're not doing anything else with the object. You are, so this is not an optimisation.

Comment: No, it's not only for that use. Check
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#updating-attributes-based-on-existing-fields
If I do `rank.ammountMatchesRanked += 1` it will access the value of `ammountMatchesRanked`, resulting in an additional query. The object hasn't been used before. Django uses a lazy mechanism which will only query when you actually use the object.

Comment: No, see my further explanation above.

Comment: But you *will* - you go on to do more manipulations after the first save(). This means that you actually do *more* database calls than necessary - the opposite of what you intended. Normally you would only do one UPDATE, your way you are doing at least two.

Comment: I see Daniel... anyways, my question wasn't really answered yet, is there any way to remove the F() from the field, or remove the field from future queries? Thanks

Comment: As I see from the documentation linked, the F() function is used to update a field using the value contained at the moment of `save`, while the standard `+=1` will use the value retrieved when the object was read from db. This can be useful when multiple users can update the same row at nearly the same time: the considered value will be always the last updated one.